# Produce well formatted nullable type syntax with Roslyn when generating language agnostic code

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm using Roslyn to create what should be a language agnostic code generator for some sort of data access layer.
It will use metadata to output the desired code.
It is expected to return C# and VB.NET versions of the code.

Current implementation is generating the desired output however the *nullable types are not well formatted*, the output contains extra white spaces.

Is there an option to ensure the nullable type generated by  `SyntaxGenerator.NullableTypeExpression` return a well formatted - no white spaces - declaration?

***Code Snippets***

This is where `SyntaxGenerator.NullableTypeExpression` is used to return a SyntaxNode corresponding to the property type.

```
    private SyntaxNode ToTypeExpression(Type type, bool nullable, SyntaxGenerator generator)
    {

        SyntaxNode baseType;
        SyntaxNode propType;

        SpecialType specialType = ToSpecialType(type);

        if(specialType == SpecialType.None)
        {
            baseType = generator.IdentifierName(type.Name);                
        }
        else
        {
            baseType = generator.TypeExpression(specialType);
        }

        if (nullable && type.IsValueType)
        {
            propType = generator.NullableTypeExpression(baseType);
        }
        else
        {
            propType = baseType;
        }

        return propType;

    }
```

This is the generated VB.NET code:

```
    Public Property Salary As Integer?
        Get
            Return GetAttributeValue(Of Integer?)("salary").Value
        End Get

        Set(value As Integer?)
            SetPropertyValue("Salary", "salary", value)
        End Set
    End Property
```

This is the C# code, *note the white spaces*:

```
    public int ? Salary
    {
        get
        {
            return GetAttributeValue<int ? >("salary").Value;
        }

        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("Salary", "salary", value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Echoing Ed, what is the error message, expected condition, etc. here?

Comment: Have you tried `.W‌​ithAdditionalAnnotat‌​ions(Formatter.Annot‌​ation)` ?

Comment: Sorry guys but I didn't understand the "down vote". @EdPlunkett and Kirk, the question is on the post subject, which ends with a question mark :-) There is no "error message" but the "unexpected condition" is the additional white space on the C# version of the nullable value. It doesn't prevent it from compiling but doesn't look right either.

Comment: @Ebrito Clearly, you've got Roslyn properly generating the exact code you want. This is a question about *formatting* the generated code, contrary to the title. Maybe that's what the -1 was about; can't say, as it wasn't me.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten that didn't change the output.

Comment: Answer provided on this post did the trick: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467295/generating-well-formatted-syntax-with-roslyn)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Formatter.Format` as suggest here: [Generating well-formatted syntax with Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33467359), removed the undesired white spaces.

```
        string textOutput;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var result = generator.CompilationUnit(declarations);

        var formattedResult = Formatter.Format(result, workspace);

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            formattedResult.WriteTo(writer);
            textOutput = writer.ToString();
        }
```